# Segmented function in R?

Tags: time-series, r, linear-regression, rstudio

Could someone please explain what psi and npsi are?

```
segmented(obj, seg.Z, psi, npsi, fixed.psi=NULL, control = seg.control(),
model = TRUE, keep.class=FALSE, ...)
```

If obj is the linear model
`seg.z` is `~X`
what is `psi` and `npsi`?

Also, if we only include: `obj`, `seg.z` and `npsi`. Would that be sufficient to estimate the breakpoints?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [documentation of the function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/segmented/versions/1.3-4/topics/segmented)? `psi` and `npsi` seem to indicate the breakpoints and the number of breakpoints respectively. According to the documentation the `psi` argument can only be left empty when "1 breakpoint has to be estimated (and the median of the segmented variable is used as a starting value)". So if that's the case for what you're trying to achieve only providing `npsi` is sufficient, otherwise it is not.

Comment: Hi, thank you. My summary output does not provide p-values, how would i know if the segments are statistically significant or not?